# React onClick function not firing

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that houses several Post components. I have onClick attributes on every Post component which should fire a simple console.log. I have no idea why it is not firing. Here is the code.

```
class Feed extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

  handleClick(){
    console.log('hello');
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='feed_container'>
        <h2 className='feed_header_text'>Followed Posts <i className="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
        <Post name='Bruce Banner' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Peter Parker' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Bruce Wayne' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Harleen Frances Quinzel' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Alan Scott' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Tony Stark' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Clark Kent' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Post name='Barry Allen' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the code of your Post component to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind the `onClick` or any other event to component.You should bind it to DOM element.

```
<Post name='Bruce Banner' onClick={this.handleClick}/> //wrong
```

instead,

define the `Post` in such way,so it accept eventHanlder as props and attach it to `Post` DOM element.

**Post component :**

```
const Post = ({handleClick})=>(<div onClick={handleClick}>Hello</div>)
```

passed `handleClick` to Post component :

```
<Post name='Bruce Banner' handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
```