# React onclick function not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Issue is Google Maps API display directions from one location to another is returning error function displayDirections() is not defined.

Unsuccessful with help from other questions so far, ex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850228/react-onclick-function-not-firing), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292763/jquery-onclick-function-not-defined)

Full code [here](https://github.com/3noki/project_6_react_neighborhood_map), been fidgeting with the quotes and single quotes etc but don't think that's the issue. This function is listed where all my other functions are called without issues. When I enter in a destination, then when the infoWindows appear, I select the View Route button, but I still get the error that displayDirections is not defined, I even moved this function up global in App.js, but I still can't figure out why this function is

Just a snip it of the code, if something's missing it's probably in the full code;

```
function displayDirections(origin) {
 hideListings()
 let directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService()
 let destinationAddress = document.getElementById('search-within-time-text').value
 let mode = document.getElementById('mode').value
     directionsService.route({
     origin: origin,
     destination: destinationAddress,
     travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode[mode]
      }, function(response, status) {
       if (status === window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          let directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map,
            directions: response,
            draggable: true,
            polylineOptions: {
              strokeColor: 'green'
            }
          }) } else {window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
        }
      })
    }

let infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: durationText + ' away, 
    ' + distanceText + '<div><input id="route" type="button" value="View Route" onclick 
    =' + '{displayDirections("origins[i]")}></input></div>'})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick not working React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401902/onclick-not-working-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this supposed to be a template literal:

```
onclick=displayDirections(`${origins[i]}`)
```

Comment: I think that you are right, but shouldn't the whole string of text be a template literal, like this `\`<div><input id="route" type="button" value="View Route" onClick=${displayDirections(origins[i])}></input></div>\``?